# Using Projection to define list of columns to select in Slick

Tags: scala, slick

I have table definition in Slick:

```
object ADB {
  extends BaseDB[A]("a")
  with PostgresDriver{
  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  ...
  def * = id ~ name ~ ... <> (A.apply _, A.unapply _)

  def forSelect = id ~ name
}
```

Is it possible to refer to `forSelect` when querying for `A`?

I want to keep the list of field to be selected in one place to be able to push `forSelect` to trait in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can accomplish what you want like this:

```
( for( a <- ADB ) yield a.forSelect ).list
```

The difference between this and what stefan.schwetschke posted is that I'm using the instance `a` to reference `forSelect` instead of accessing it from the `ADB` object itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
...map(ADB.forSelect)
```

or

```
for( ... ) yield ADB.forSelect
```

The following worked for me:

```
import scala.slick.driver.H2Driver.simple._
import Database.threadLocalSession


object ADB extends Table[(Long, String)]("a") {
  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def * = id ~ name 

  def forSelect = id ~ name
}

Database.forURL("jdbc:h2:mem:test1", driver = "org.h2.Driver") withSession {
  ( for( a <- ADB ) yield ADB.forSelect ).list
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. The main difference between you example and mine is in `extends BaseDB[A]("a")`. I used mapping to object, but not for tuple. I try to use your solution, but again got `SlickException: Select(TableNode, "id") found. This is typically caused by an attempt to use a "raw" table object directly in a query without introducing it through a generator`. Any ideas?